# set of radio button validation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate 2 sets of radio button using Javascript. It is working with one set but not when I add another radio set (secondtime visitor). Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" action="#" method="post"> 
    First time visitor?:<br/>
    <label for="s1">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="firsttime" value="1"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="s2">No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="firsttime" value="2"/>

    <br/>     

    Second time visitor?:<br/>
    <label for="s1">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="secondTime" value="1"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="s2">No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="secondTime" value="2"/>

    <br/>     

    <button type="submit" name="nextBTN" onclick="return validateForm();">Next</button><br/>
</form>
```

And Javascript code:

```
function validateForm() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("firsttime");
    var radios2 = document.getElementsByName("secondtime");
    var formValid = false;

    var i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
        i++;        
    }

    var j = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios2.length) {
        if (radios2[j].checked) formValid = true;
        j++;        
    }


    if (!formValid) alert("Must check some option!");
    return formValid;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, I can see that in your second while loop, you still check the `radios` variable instead of the `radios2` variable.

You also used the `i` variable instead of `j` in the second loop. And you weren't consistent with the capitalization of `secondTime` (vs `secondtime`).

Here's a working version of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/8edCn/

EDIT: Updated version per your comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8edCn/2/

Comment: that's just a typo, I changed that.

Comment: That wasn't your only typo; I updated my response with a fix.

Comment: this only works with first set, 2nd set doesn't validate. When I check firsttime visitor radio button and hit Next, it says success. I want to validate both firsttime and secondtime (both needs to be checked).. Sorry for the typos

Comment: Ah, that is because you only had the one boolean, and it would be true if either were checked. Here's an update that checks both: http://jsfiddle.net/8edCn/2/

Comment: Thanks! I was just working on it, but your code came faster then mine, works great, thanks!